# Apache Batik Text Wrapped SVG

Tags: java, svg, batik

Is there a Batik-compatible way to do automatic text wrapping with SVG?

I've looked all over the internet and can't find anything definitively. `foreignObject` with HTML doesn't work. I saw that `flowRoot` and friends should work, but I can't seem to get one to work properly. I can't find a conclusively working example either.

An SVG sample that works would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`<flowRoot>` was a proposed element in the SVG 1.2 specification.  That specification was never ratified, and those text flow elements weren't implemented by any browsers or renderers other than the Inkscape vector editor.

If you know you are going to only be in a browser environment, you can use `<foreignObject>` element. But if the SVG needs to work outside of a browser, you can't use ithat.

The upcoming SVG2 spec includes features for wrapping text and placing it inside shapes.  For example there is the [`inline-size`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-InlineSize) property. However nothing supports that yet.

The only renderer-agnostic option right now is to layout the text rows yourself using separate `<text>` or `<tspan>` elements.

Comment: I specifically need one that works with Batik. Having browser support is a nice-to-have, but not required. Working with Batik is.